# Callback function for database query returns nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So I do this:

```
module.exports.checkEmailInUse = (email) => {

    connection.query('SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE email = ?',
        [
            email
        ],
        function(err, rows, fields) {


            console.log(rows.length);


            if(rows.length > 0){

                return true;

            }
            else{

                return false;

            }

       }
    );



}
```

This table is blank. I get 0 returned as it should. But over in this other file I do this:

```
if(Database.checkEmailInUse(email)){

    callback({success: "false", message: "Email Already In Use"});

    return false;
}
```

This should NOT fire because this returns 0.... but it does.

But now if I return them as strings like:

```
return "true";
```

and:

```
if(Database.checkEmailInUse(email) == "true")
```

It will work.

This is my first project with NodeJS and am stumped here.

***EDIT***
ANSWER. Thanks qqilihq!! :

```
module.exports.checkEmailInUse = (email) => {

var queryTheEmail = (email, callback)=>{

    connection.query('SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE email = ?',
        [
            email
        ],
        function(err, rows) {

            if (err) {
                callback(err,null);
            }

            else{
                callback(null,rows);
            }


        }
    );

}

queryTheEmail(email, (err, rows) => {


    if (err) {

        console.error('SQL error: ', err);
        return false;

    }

    if(rows.length > 0){

        return true;

    }
    else{

        return false;

    }


});


}
```

Comment: The problem is, your `checkEmailInUse` function actually returns nothing. The DB query happens asynchronously: check the nesting of the functions. You'll need to refactor this, to either use callbacks or return promises. Either way, this has *nothing* to do with booleans in particular.

Comment: Pro off-topic side-tip: if you ever find yourself doing a return true else false, it's probably needless code. Your `if (rows.length > 0) ...` can be replaced by `return rows.length > 0`

Comment: @LiamGray that's what I initially had and have been taking crap shoots at the problem since lol.

Comment: @qqilihq I thought the `function(err, rows, fields) {` was the call back for the query. Alright, looking into it now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to maintain the asynchronous nature from that point. Simply put: As soon as parts of your code contain async. parts, everything becomes asynchronous.

Comment: @qqilihq Yeah, I'm quickly beginning to learn that now lol. I have the solution now using a separate callback. I'll post it as soon as I test it and if you answer, I'll give you the credit for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, your `checkEmailInUse` function actually returns *nothing*. The DB query happens asynchronously: Check the nesting of the functions. As a (simplified) rule of thumb: **Asynchronity is viral** -- as soon as your code contains asynchronous parts, everything which makes use of it needs to take care of asynchronity as well.

You'll need to refactor this, to either use callbacks or return promises. Following example shows how to do it using callbacks (and some additional code cleanup):

```
module.exports.checkEmailInUse = (email, callback) => {
    connection.query('SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE email = ?',
        [
            email
        ],
        function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, rows.length > 0);
        }
    );
}
```

Then, use the `checkEmailInUse` function as follows:

```
Database.checkEmailInUse(email, function(err, exists) {
    if (err) {
        return callback({success: "false", message: "Error when checking the DB"});
    }
    if (exists) {
        callback({success: "false", message: "Email Already In Use"});
    } else {
        callback({success: "true", message: "Come in!"});
    }
});
```

Once, you're getting familiar to the asynchronous concept and your codebase grows, it's worth considering to introduce promises in order to avoid the so called 'callback hell' and make you code much more readable (or use helpers such as async.js).

Either way, this has nothing to do with booleans in particular as the original question title assumed.

Comment: @user2287474 You're welcome! I'll edit the question's title, which makes it probably helpful for more people having a similar problem.